# How can I use part of a CSS function name (eg. 'Y' from 'translateY') as a variable?

Tags: sass

Not exactly sure how to ask this one, so I'll demonstrate with code:

I have a mixin that I'm hoping I can refactor:

```
@mixin center-align($dir, $position: relative) {
  position: $position;

  @if $dir == Y {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate + inspect($dir) + (-50%);
  } @else if $dir == X {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  } @else {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }

}
```

Instead of doing the @if loop, I'd like to do something like this:

```
transform: translate + $dir + (-50%);
```

or

```
transform: translate+$dir(-50%);
```

or

```
transform: translate + inspect($dir) + (-50%);
```

but each of these outputs a variation of this:

```
transform: translateY-50%;
```

without the parens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use string interpolation here:

```
.foo {
  $foo: 'X';
  transform: #{"translate#{$foo}(50%)"};
}
```

Output:

```
.foo {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

Comment: Brain must not have been working correctly. Thank you!